# How to use the opengl in the QGraphicsView, and then compile to wasm?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, webassembly

I create a Qt project, in this project, I use the QGraphicsView to show a circle. i try to use opengl to show it, this function is, and it is successful in the PC program, but when I compile to the wasm with emscripten, it is failed to show the graphics in the web. I do not know why?

here is the method to use opengl to render the graphic.

```
setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
```